# How to Vertically Align a Table in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I vertically align a table in the middle of the screen with css?

Comment: @think123: That question is a duplicate, not this one.

Answer (score 1):

Generally something along the lines of this works pretty well in any block element with a defined height.

```
table { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -50%;
}
```

Centering on the page is harder since you don't have a defined height, but I think this works.

```
html {
 height: 100%;
}
```

You may encounter some browser differences, act accordingly.

Comment: Usually I wind up with something like this, except with a wrapper class around the table (because you need the top property to be on the outer element and the margin-top to be on the inner element.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly said, just make your body a table, because vertical-align does work on table-cells:

```css
body, html { 
  height: 100%; 
}

body { 
  display: table; 
}

#wrapper { 
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80%;
}
```

This will vertical align your pagewrapper to middle and let it be fluid 80%

Answer (score 0):

If you can give the table a fixed height, then feel free to adapt the CSS from [this site](http://cleanteq.com/) I've just done.

Bit complicated to explain, but basically you set a 1 pixel high 'horizon' at 50% height of the screen around your content, then offset the top of the element to be centred (i.e. your table) by 50% of its height.

EDIT: [Here's the article](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html) I originally made my solution from, with explanation & everything.