# HTML - Vertically Align a Table

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Vertically Align a Table in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437333/how-to-vertically-align-a-table-in-css)

I would like to place my table smack dab in the center of a page. IT is easy horizontally align it just using

```
<table align="center"></table>
```

But it will not allow this:

```
<table align="center" valign="center">
```

I also cant put the valign in a div because it is not a valid attribute.

I have the idea of making a cell take up an the entire page then using:

```
<Table align="center" width="100%">
<tr><td valign="middle" height="100%"></td></tr>
</table>
```

But that too does not work because my `<td>` does not take up the entire page. When I set its height to 100% it only takes up the amount of space necessary.

Any Ideas? CSS code would be great help also.

Comment: It's not impossible, but there are issues with every solution. It is, admittedly, a shortcoming of CSS, and it would be awesome of the W3C would come up with a standard solution to the problem of vertical centering.

Comment: From our friends at tutorialzine.com
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.pmob.co.uk/pob/vertical-center1.htm

After you follow that link, right click the page that opened, and view the source code.

You'll notice that IE is tricky because they use conditional commenting (if you're not used to them, it's tricky). What they are doing is taking the height of the window at line 48 of the code and putting the box at 50% of the window's current height, so it even works when resized.

For the other browsers, it should be pretty clear how they do it...using a combination of position, valign, and text align to achieve desired effect.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It works if you set the object's positioning to be absolute.

Here's an example (I only tried it on Safari):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dead Center</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .dead_center {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 30%;
        height: 30%;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="dead_center">
      <tr>
        <td>My centered table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

No need for any deprecated attributes like align.

Comment: Add another 19 table rows and it's no longer centered.